# Assign different products to different stores and display products per store in backend

Tags: magento

I have a website with 5 stores, with one store view (German) for each. I want to add some products to the first store, some other products to the second store, and so on. How do I do this? Also, I have a completely custom-made page in the backend where products are displayed, and can be selected and exported. I want to be able to filter the products based on which store they are assigned to. How do I detect in my code which store a product is assigned to?

Thanks!

UPDATE: Okay, I think I found a way to do it - by assigning different root categories to the different stores. The root category can then be both assigned in the backend and detected in code. Do you think this method works, or am I on the wrong track? Thanks!

Comment: I think different root categories is not only the way to go, it is what they were designed for. That is the reason for having a choice of roots when setting up stores. You should post that as an answer to your own question then accept it, that way anyone reading this will know that you figured it out correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a way to do it - by assigning different root categories to the different stores. The root category can then be both assigned in the backend and detected in code.

Answer (score 0):

Make the storefronts and add all products to your default storefront then switch store scope and disable/enable your items on storefronts that they belong.

website (GERMANY)
 - store 1
 - store 2
 - store 3
 - store 4 
 - store 5

If you get the product collection you can add store filter to it and filter by store-code/id

Comment: Thanks Anton S, but it already worked out satisfactorily using different root categories for each store.