# MultiStore with different products

Tags: magento, product

I have a Magento Store configured to use a single website with two stores (and one store view for each).

Both stores must have different products. When I created them, each store had its own Root Category, so I expected Magento to divide products by the associated category. Somehow this worked on my local test at first, but didn't on production and after changing some categories locally it didn't work - even changing it back did not fix this problem.

Searching I found that I could change the status per store view, but at the side of product status, it says "Website" and when I change it, both views change. I could change visibility but I'm not sure if that won't slow down the store.  So, two questions:

1. Is it possible to separate the products for each store based on the
   root category?
2. Is visibility per store view optimized? (I currently have about 500 products, 400 in one store and 100 on the other, and I don't want to slow down the store)

**Edit:**
Couldn't find a solution for this, used a workaround instead:

I have this on my CMS Homepage:

```
{{block type="catalog/product_list_random" name="home_products" template="catalog/product/list.phtml"}}
```

And this was showing the products from the other store. So I extended the Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List class to include a filter by the current store root category id:

```
$_rootcatID = Mage::app()->getStore()->getRootCategoryId();
$collection
    ->joinField('category_id', 'catalog/category_product', 'category_id', 'product_id = entity_id', null, 'left')
    ->addAttributeToFilter('category_id', array('in' => $_rootcatID));
```

The products from the other store will still show on searches, but that's ok for me.

Answer (score 0):

When editing a product you should see a tab called 'Websites'. From there you can assign or remove products to/from a specific website. You can even bulk change the websites by selecting products in the grid and selecting the action Change attributes. Again you should see a 'websites' tab.
As for the visibility, there is no problem. If you enable the flat catalog for each store view a new table will be created and the visibility will be just a simple flag used in the `where` statements of selects.

Comment: I have a single website with two stores, so the "Websites" tab on products have the checkbox only on the website, not on the stores or even store views. About flat catalog, is there any drawback on using it? I searched a bit and it seems to improve performance, but why isn't it enabled by default?

Comment: In this case you should rethink the architecture. Maybe you should use 2 websites, each one with a store view. As for the flat catalog, is not enabled by default because a reindex is required to build the flat tables. If it was enabled by default you will get an error.

Comment: I did it like this because the tutorial I used said products are per store (http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/overview-how-multiple-websites-stores-work/) and it did work at first on my local machine. Also there are other places saying that changing Root Category (which is store based) separate products (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4507608/assign-different-products-to-different-stores-and-display-products-per-store-in). I can't understand if Magento changed the way it works or I configured something wrong.